# Monte Carlo Method. Triple Integral. Python. unsupported operand parent(s) for '+'

Tags: python, typeerror, montecarlo

I try to approximate triple integral ∫∫∫xyzdV , where S=[0,1]×[0,1]×[0,1] using Monte Carlo method.
I have this code:

```
from numpy import *
import time
from scipy.integrate import tplquad
numpoints=100000 # number of random sample points
I2d=0.0     # initialize value
I2dsquare=0.0   # initialize to allow for calculation of variance
for n in xrange(numpoints):
  x=random.uniform()
  y=random.uniform()
  z=random.uniform()
  func = lambda x,y,z: x*y*z
  x1,x2 = 0, 1
  y1,y2 = lambda x: 0,lambda x: 1
  z1,z2 = lambda x, y: 0,lambda x, y: 1
  I2d += tplquad(func, x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2)
  I2dsquare += (tplquad(func, x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2))**2

I2d=I2d/numpoints
I2dsquare=I2dsquare/numpoints
EstimError=4*sqrt( (I2dsquare - I2d**2)/numpoints) # estimated error
I2d=4*I2d
print "Value:  %f" %I2d
print "Error estimate: %f" %EstimError
```

And I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    for n in xrange(numpoints):
File "", line 1, in <module>

File "/tmp/tmpx_9bf5/___code___.py", line 17, in <module>
  I2d += tplquad(func, x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2)
File "element.pyx", line 999, in    sage.structure.element.ModuleElement.__iadd__ (sage/structure/element.c:8285)
 File "coerce.pyx", line 797, in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel_cache_maps.bin_op (sage/structure/coerce.c:7467)
TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for '+': 'Real Field with 53 bits  of precision' and '<type 'tuple'>'
```

I understand that there is different types in this code but I do not understand how to fix it. If I try to do this code for quadratic equation, for example, everything is OK but integral unfortunately do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html

`scipy.integrate.tplquad` returns a tuple `(y, abserr)`.

I think you want this:

```
I2d += tplquad(func, x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2)[0]
```

(I don't completely understand this problem mathematically so I hope it's not wrong.)